# JBOSS EAP vs Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, ejb-3.0, wildfly-10

I have used JBOSS application server at a high level wherein we write an EJB code and Infa team deploy. I wanted to know more about it. I read online and I have come across the terms like: `Wildfly` , `EAP`.

I tried to configure JBOSS "server" in my eclipse and I can see the following while adding the Server (Window -> Show View -> Server)

## Related to WildFly:

[image]

## Related to EAP:

[image]

Going by this, are both EAP and Wildfly the application server by JBOSS? What is the difference between these two?

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: They renamed JBoss AS to Wildfly starting with version 8

Comment: Thanks for clarification. What is EAP?

Comment: Look at the linked question they go through all of that